# Generate non-negative random value slightly above or below a number

Tags: php, math, random

I need to slightly scramble real numbers in a report.  The values are typically between 0 and 1000, with most being small numbers containing decimals with a scale of 2.

Some examples:

```
32.1
0.10
0.02
0.01
```

I put together this simple function to scramble the values slightly:

```
function tickle_int($v)
{
    $tickled = $v + (mt_rand(-40, 40) / 100);

    if ($tickled==$v)
    {
        $tickled = tickle_int($v);
    }
    return $tickled;
}
```

But I'm finding that the returned value is often negative.  If I change the low value of mt_rand to 0, I only get scrambled values that are greater than the original value, reducing randomness.

How could this function be modified to only return a non-negative value that is randomly above or below the passed input?

**Edit to add** I need to avoid 0.  The scrambled value needs to be non-negative and not zero.  The kicker is passing .01.   I need a way of randomzing that to values such as .009, .02, .011, ect -- while continuing to significantly randomize larger values.

Comment: $number = mt_rand(0,1000).'.'.mt_rand(0,9).mt_rand(0,9) ?

Comment: KA, $tickled needs to be based on the passed value $v, and needs to be relatively close to $v.  I could end up with a wildly out of range number randomizing as you suggest here.  If I just needed any random real number, yours would work.

Comment: why not add `if ($tickled==$v || $tickled < 0)` on your code?

Comment: Did that, and it works with a small set of data (if true, just get another random value)..  If I pass a large set of values (say, 1 million), this chokes my report as there are a lot of negative numbers with the function in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit it:

```
$tickled = $v + ( mt_rand( $v*(-1), 40) / 100 );
```

Comment: I think mt_rand will return null if it's going to return negative number.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move `-40` outside of `mt_rand`:

```
function tickle_int($v, $w)
{
    $tickled = $v + (mt_rand(0, 2 * $w) - ($v >= $w? $w : $v)) / 100;

    if ($tickled==$v)
    {
        $tickled = tickle_int($v);
    }
    return $tickled;
}

tickle_int(0.5, 40);
```

Comment: If I pass a number less than .1, but greater than 0, $tickled sometimes still returns a negative number.   For example, I passed .09, and $tickled became -0.29.

Comment: @a coder So just append restriction: `if ($tickled < 0) $tickled = 0;`

Comment: I need it to be a randomized, non negative number based around the passed $v.  Otherwise that would work.

Comment: I don't understand, what is your problem?

Comment: Sorry - got confused with an edit.  What is $w in your updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
function tickle_int($v)
{
    $random = mt_rand(40, 80);
    $tickled = $v + (($random - 40) / 100);

    if ($tickled==$v)
    {
        $tickled = tickle_int($v);
    }
    print_r($tickled);
}
```

Comment: This always returns a $tickled value greater than the passed $v.  My question states a need for the scrambled number to be randomly above and below the passed value - but not negative.   The kicker is passing .01.  I should get some randomness like .009, .02, .011, ect.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care too much about the random distribution, then you could simply do

```
if ($tickled < 0)
{
    $tickled = 0;
}
return $tickled;
```

Otherwise, you need to modify the min parameter passed to `mt_rand` to be dependent on `$v`.

Comment: The scrambled number must be randomized and while zero is an occasional random value, setting all negative values to zero defeats the purpose.

Comment: You should follow my second point then. You'll probably need the `max` function.